# MFi product look up

Tags: hardware, accessories, guided-access

I used to check MFi product using [mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getAPS](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getAPS) provided by Apple. It looks like they have turned it off. I would like to know if there is any alternative available?

Comment: https://mfi.apple.com/en/faqs.html At the bottom of this page it seems like you can look up at least the manufacture name.

Comment: @X_841 yes you are right about that. I am not sure why they changed it, but anyway I found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [mfi.apple.com/account/accessory-search](https://mfi.apple.com/account/accessory-search)

> **Search for accessories that have completed MFi certification**
>
> Once an accessory has completed MFi certification requirements and is reported to Apple as sold/distributed, it will be searchable in our public database of authorized Lightning, headset, charging, and iAP-based MFi accessories.